# Android - Problemn when setting visibility in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

When I change visibility to GONE with CoordinatorLayout as parent view, the AppBarLayout already take place, but when I use the LinearLayout, i haven't this problem.

I want to use CoordinatorLayout for the slide of the AppBarLayout when scrolling RecyclerView.

[image]

Comment: You are talking about the visibility (GONE) of which layout ? What do you mean by AppBarLayout already take place? Can you post some some code and make things clear in the question?

Comment: Look the screenshots

Comment: can you also post the layout xml file?

Answer (score 1):

First in your `AppBarLayout` you should add:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
```

and in the FrameLayout you should add:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`